# How do I use the Request function in node.js within a for loop and have it return output in correct order?

Tags: javascript, node.js, request, cheerio

I've been using request to iterate through several XML entries and return every article, date, and url to the console by using cheerio.js. The main issue is that the output will appear in a different order each time, as Request is an asynchronous function. I'm really inexperienced with javascript in general, and was wondering how I could retrieve consistent output (I've been reading about async and promises, I'm just unsure how to implement them).
Here is my code:

```
var count = 0;
for(var j = 0; j < arrNames.length; j++){
  request('http://dblp.org/search/publ/api?q=' + arrNames[j], function(error, response, html){
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200){
      var $ = cheerio.load(html, {xmlMode: true});
      console.log($('query').text()+'\n');

      $('title').each(function(i, element){
        var title = $('title').eq(i).text();
        var year = Number($('year').eq(i).text());
        var url = $('ee').eq(i).text();

        if (year >= arrTenures[count]){
          console.log(title);
          console.log(year);
          console.log(url + '\n');
        }
      });

      count++;
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: If you use promises it will be something like this `Promise.all( arrNames.map( name => request("http://dblp.org/search/publ/api?q=" + name) ).then( arrayWithResult => { /* do your thing here*/ })`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though you've already found a solution, I thought I'd show you how you would do this using ES6 promises (a more modern approach for managing multiple asynchronous operations):

```
const rp = require('request-promise');

Promise.all(arrNames.map(item => {
    return rp('http://dblp.org/search/publ/api?q=' + item).then(html => {
        const $ = cheerio.load(html, {xmlMode: true});

        return $('title').map(function(i, element){
            const title = $(element).text();
            const year = Number($('year').eq(i).text());
            const url = $('ee').eq(i).text();
            return {title, year, url};
        }).get();
    });
})).then(results => {
    // results is an array of arrays, in order
    console.log(results);
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

This offers several advantages:

1. `Promise.all()` puts the results in order for you.
2. `rp()` checks the 2xx status for you.
3. This can be chained/sequenced with other asynchronous operations more easily.
4. Error handling is simpler and low level errors are propagated out to the top level for you automatically.
5. This is throw-safe (if async errors are thrown, they are captured and propagated).

Comment: This is a very helpful answer, it indeed would be very nice to have everything returned it their proper order. This makes promises appear much less difficult than I thought, it was hard to glean from unrelated examples. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to capture the iteration number of each request, so use `forEach` and utilize its second parameter, which indicates the iteration index:

```
arrNames.forEach((q, requestIndex) => {
  request('http://dblp.org/search/publ/api?q=' + q, (error, response, html) => {
    if (error || response.statusCode == 200) return;
    var $ = cheerio.load(html, {
      xmlMode: true
    });
    console.log($('query').text() + '\n');
    $('title').each(function(i, element) {
      var title = $('title').eq(i).text();
      var year = Number($('year').eq(i).text());
      var url = $('ee').eq(i).text();
      if (year >= arrTenures[requestIndex]) {
        console.log(title);
        console.log(year);
        console.log(url + '\n');
      }
    });
  });
});
```

As a side note, consistent indentation really improves code readability - you might consider a linter.

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick response! You were very correct in me trying to capture the iteration number for each request, and this was just the thing that fixed it! Also my indentation is slightly better in real life, this was my first time posting on SO, so I screwed up the formatting. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

On your first try, you might have tried:

```
if (year >= arrTenures[j]) {
```

But noticed that didn't work. This is because of scoping issues

You can solve your problem by using an iterator like `forEach()`, or simply changing your for loop to use `let`:

```
for(let j = 0; j < arrNames.length; j++){
```

Now you can just use `j` in your check instead of count.

---

The real question though, is why are `arrTenures` and `arrNames` separate arrays? Their information clearly relates to each other, so relying on the array index to couple them seems like a bad idea. Instead, you should try and keep a single array of objects with all related information. For example:

```
[
  { name: 'some name', tenures: 2 },
  { name: 'another', tenures: 5 }
]
```

Comment: Huh, I didn't know you could do that with arrays in Javascript, thanks for the idea!

Comment: Then you can do things like `item.name` or `item.tenures` :)

Comment: Ha I was literally just googling how to access those elements! thanks